# Catalog search gives me a blank page

Tags: search, catalogsearch

When I try to search something using Magento catalog search, it gives me back a blank page?

I am using these settings

- minimum length: 3 characters before start search
- maximum length 128
- search engine: mysql fulltext
- Enable Search Recommendations: yes
- Search Recommendations Count: 5
- Show Results Count for Each Recommendation: no
- search type: combined

Fabio Codebue